# Ubuntu is not finding hard disks and partition table is empty

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying do a dual boot installation of Ubuntu using USB but when I go to install, the partition table is empty. When I then ran-

```
sudo dmraid -Er /dev/sda
```

it said that there were no block devices found. When I ran GParted, the only device that it recognized was the USB itself, but not the hard disk. 
How should I go about this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user535733 Sorry, I don´t understand your comment... But perhaps it is because I am also new to Ubuntu...

Comment: @user535733 I found on line that I should run that comment if the partitioning window was empty, is there anything else I could do to fix that primary issue?

Comment: @William First open UEFI setting and find the menu where SATA mode is. You'll likely find that it's set to RAID and that is incompatible. Boot back to Windows, install AHCI drivers (google it) in Windows (fail to do this and your Windows won't boot following the next step). Then open again UEFI settings and change the SATA mode to AHCI. Now you're drives will be visible to the Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS settings and see if the disks are set to RAID mode. If they are, then that's why no disk is seen, and you need to change to AHCI... but follow these instructions, or Windows won't boot any more...

See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- If you don’t see Command Prompt listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type cmd
- Right-click the result and select Run as administrator
- Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
- If this command does not work for you, try bcdedit /set safeboot minimal
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
- If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.